# Allowing access to subnets openvpn access server

Tags: openvpn

I have a centos server running a openvpn access server. On that server I am running a windows server in virtual box. On the centos server I am running the vpn with a network address 172.27.224.0 with 20 bits. The windows server is running a dchp server giving ip's of 192.168.1.0-200. When i try to connect to the widows shared folder from the vpn i can't using the name of the server but i can from the ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are running a routed openVPN installation. In this configuration Netbios broadcasts are not forwarded via the VPN connection and you cannot connect using the Netbios name. See  http://openvpn.net/index.php/download/60-open-source/faq.html for details on what is forwarded in which configuration. You may also install a DNS Server on your windows server ( why do you run the DHCP on the virtual machine anyway? ) to resolve network names.

Comment: i have a dns server on the windows server